# Installing svn on a local computer

Tags: apache2, svn

I just tried to install svn on the ubuntu but I'm getting the following error

> ERROR: Config file dav_svn.conf not properly enabled:
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf is a real file, not touching it
>   dpkg: error processing libapache2-svn (--configure):

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What subversion client are you installing? What command did you use to install it? Or did you use the package manager?

Comment: I used the following command sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn

Comment: Erm... Don't you need the client instead of the server version? Start with `sudo apt-get install subversion`, then, do you already have Apache 2.2 if you really want the server version?

Comment: I already installed the apache and subversion

Comment: Yes I already installed the apache 2.2, i installed the lamp

Comment: You don't understand, I'll ask it otherwise: Are you trying to host a SVN Repository or just use one?

Comment: I just trying to make a home server using ubuntu. For me the most important part the trac and the svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes I already installed the apache 2.2, i installed the lamp

I would suggest you to *start from scratch*, LAMP comes with a pre-configured Apache 2.2 which might be tampering with your current settings, get rid of LAMP and do `sudo apt-get install apache2`.

Who knows, the error might suddenly be gone!

---

The error itself mentions a specific configuration file, have you followed the instructions in that file?
You can edit the file with 
`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`

If there is nothing to see there or if it's an example, try renaming the file temporarily...

But I bet it has to do with the LAMP installation.